# Documentation to release and deliver a C++ application to the final customer

Tags: c++

I would like to know generally what the process is to deliver a C++ application (binaries only, not source code) to a customer in the commercial world.

For example, what kind of documentation is generally delivered when only the binaries are delivered (a VDD, SVD, README, etc. etc.???).
What kind of documentation is delivered when both, the source code and the binaries are delivered?

I have always worked on DoD programs, and normally a VDD/SVD is delivered along with the source code.  The VDD/SVD includes instructions on how to build binaries from the source code, so normally a list of binaries is not required to be on the VDD/SVD.

For commercial customers not getting the source code (only binaries), what is normally delivered in terms of documentation?
THanks.

Comment: This question is about packaging/distribution/documentation and not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are delivering binaries only, there should be a manual describing all the use cases for the user and a description of all the files and processes (including installation and removal) an administrator should be aware of without going into details about the source.

If you deliver the source, you should export Doxygen code comments, or whatever equivalent you are using, into a some mutually agreed upon format. There should also be a description of how the source is organized if it does not appear in the code comments somewhere. This in addition to the manuals.

This information is from my personal experience about what keeps customers happy. I do not really know what is "normal" per se.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  That's what I will do. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I hope my advice does not cause you any problems down the line :)